# Bloch ball for a given transformation: Applying transformations to regions

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

How can we apply transformations to Regions in the Wolfram language?

For example, given the transformation $r_x \rightarrow r_x\sqrt{1-g}, r_y \rightarrow r_y \sqrt{1-g}, r_z \rightarrow g + r_z (1-g)$, how can one apply such transformation to a unit sphere regions representing [Bloch sphere/ball](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere) ?

```
r = Region[Sphere[]]
```

Edit: What I originally meant by "show" is to take a unit sphere and then apply this transformation and see how it changes its shape/position (given that it may shrink and at the same time its center can be displaced).

Comment: I am little bit confused. You want a graphic representation of the Bloch same as given in Wikipedia page?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, or if it is even related to Mathematica. "how can one show **this**" <- What do you mean by "this"? What do you mean by "show? (Prove?) Please rewrite the question to prevent it from getting closed.

Comment: The question was clear enough for me to give an acceptable answer. I have edited the question to clarify a bit and suggest we re-open it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Region[Sphere[]]
```

[image]

```
tr = With[{g=0.7},
   Composition[
   TranslationTransform[{0, 0, g}],
   ScalingTransform[{Sqrt[1-g],Sqrt[1-g],(1-g)}]
 ]
];
```

[image]

```
Region[
  TransformedRegion[Sphere[],tr]
  ,PlotTheme->"Detailed"
  ,PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @rhermans. How can one use some mesh function so that the curvature is visible clearly?

Comment: For that please ask a new question.

Comment: It would also be nice if we could put axes with the origin at x=y=z=0.

Comment: My question time is over, can post only after 40 minutes! It would be nice if you could do it here.

Comment: @Zubin No, while clarification and improvements in questions are desirable, here we normally consider it a bad idea to move the goalpost and add new requests to old questions. You need to ask a new question.

Comment: Okay, just asked a separate question here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/255499/drawing-corrdinate-axes-in-a-3d-plot