# Drawing coordinate axes in a 3D plot

Tags: plotting

How can one draw the coordinate system, i.e., x, y, and z axes with origin at (0,0,0) in the following plot:

```
tr = With[{g=0.7},
   Composition[
   TranslationTransform[{0, 0, g}],
   ScalingTransform[{Sqrt[1-g],Sqrt[1-g],(1-g)}]
 ]
];

Region[
  TransformedRegion[Sphere[],tr]
  ,PlotTheme->"Detailed"
  ,PlotRange->{{-1,1},{-1,1},{-1,1}}
]
```

Comment: Does adding `AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}` do what you want?

Comment: @CarlWoll, thanks. It does bring axes in the plot, but they look too thin with small labelling ( I mean numbers on axes look very tiny). Is there a way to make these axes bold with nice arrow tips and also increase the size of numbering on axes?

Comment: Try ' AxesStyle'